# Telebot python ввод в вводе

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста как с библиотекой telebot в python сделать "ввод в вводе". После ввода данных мне нужно чтобы бот запрашивал имя. Сейчас бот запрашивает данные и сразу записывает эти данные в имя хотя это разное.

```
def func(message):
    global con
    if con == 1:
        num = int(data[0]["nom"])
        for i in range(1, num):
                print(data[i]["номер"])
                if str(data[i]["номер"]) == message.text:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Присоеденился")
                    con = 0
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться")
                    markup.add(btn1)
                    # Тут нужно запросить имя
```

Пробовали создать цикличность функции, но не вышло.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `bot.register_next_step_handler`

Создайте отдельную функцию например `reg_user` и в ней пропишите данные, которые нужно запрашивать у пользователя

Например:

```
def reg_user(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваше имя") # сообщение которое отправится пользователю
    # обработчик ждет ответ от пользователя и запускает следующую функцию 
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reg_user_two) 

def reg_user_two(message):
   user_feedback = message.text # сохраняем ответ в переменную
   msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите вашу фамилию")
   # передаем ответ в следующую функцию
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reg_user_two, user_feedback) 
# далее по аналогии сколько угодно раз
```

В конце просто выведите результаты ваших переменных в чат или сохраните в БД, как угодно

И не забывайте юзать документацию